Are duplicate accounts in LUTs allowed?
If i try to extend an existing LUT, what will happend if i pass accounts that are already entered in the table? Will it be ignored? or will it be entered as a duplicate entry?
I also would like to know if it is possible to delete entries from the table.
Assistance is much appreciated

Duplicate entries are valid, though not very useful in most cases :). You can see a LUT with duplicate entries I created here, which I simply did by calling extendLookupTable with the same address twice.
You can't delete entries from a LUT though. The supported operations are
createLookupTable
freezeLookupTable
extendLookupTable
deactivateLookupTable
closeLookupTable

